# Re-Install Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-8

I bought a [HP laptop](https://www.amazon.in/HP-15-AC072TX-15-6-inch-Windows-Graphics/dp/B011298G12) couple of years back that originally came with genuine Windows 8.1.  I completely formatted this windows and installed Ubuntu.  I don't remember whether I had upgraded 8.1 to 10 before formatting it.

Is it possible to recover the licence key for the original windows? If so, how do I go about installing windows 8/10 on top of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PC came with Windows 8.1, it should have a Windows sticker attached somewhere. If this sticker is present, you have an embedded license. Windows Setup will automatically detect and use this license.

Windows 10 will of course not use a Windows 8.1 license. Instead, if you did upgrade while the free upgrade was available, your PC’s “signature” has been registered with Microsoft. Just install Windows 10 and it will automatically activate.

In both cases, no key is required. Prompts for a key in Windows 10 Setup can be skipped.

If you install Windows 10 and it does *not* activate, you can still purchase a license and activate it using that, without having to reinstall again.

btw: A Windows 8.1 key/license cannot be used to activate Windows 8. You really need Windows 8.1.